# NSIS : Aborting creation process

Tags: timestamp, nsis, sign

I want to create an installer with signing without time stamp as my code below.
But the build failed, aborting creation process in line:

```
!system "$\"${SIGNTOOL_PATH}$\" sign /f $\"${KEY_PATH}$\" /p ${PASSWORD} /d $\"${FULL_NAME}$\" /du $\"http://www.companywebsite.com$\" $\"$%TEMP%\uninstall.exe$\"" = 0
```

So I commented this line and make build it again, then I got an installer with signing. But I think this is not correct to comment the line.

```
!ifdef INNER
OutFile "$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe"
SetCompress off
!else

 !system "$\"${NSISDIR}\makensis$\" /DINNER /O..\..\log_project.txt /DVERSION=${VERSION} /DRELEASE=${RELEASE} /DLICENSE=${LICENSE} /DBUILDID=${BUILDID} PROJECT.nsi" = 0

!system "$%TEMP%\tempinstaller.exe" = 2

!if "${SERVER_TIMEOUT}" == "true"
!if "${SIGNTOOL_PATH}" != ""
             !error
     !endif
!else

     !if "${SIGNTOOL_PATH}" != ""
        !echo "Return Value"
             !if "${TIMESTAMP_URL}" == ""
                !system "$\"${SIGNTOOL_PATH}$\" sign /f $\"${KEY_PATH}$\" /p ${PASSWORD} /d $\"${FULL_NAME}$\" /du $\"http://www.companywebsite.com$\" $\"$%TEMP%\uninstall.exe$\"" = 0
             !else
                !system "$\"${SIGNTOOL_PATH}$\" sign /f $\"${KEY_PATH}$\" /p ${PASSWORD} /d $\"${FULL_NAME}$\" /du $\"http://www.companywebsite.com$\" /t $\"${TIMESTAMP_URL}$\" $\"$%TEMP%\uninstall.exe$\"" = 0
             !endif
     !endif
  !endif

  OutFile "${OUTPUT_DIR}\${SHORT_NAME}-${VERSION}-${RELEASE}.exe"
  SetCompressor /SOLID lzma
!endif
```

Do you know? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What package are you trying to build?  Have you gone to the NullSoft Homepage for support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had been fixed now, I changed the signtool.exe path.
from

```
 <property name="sign.tool" value="tools/signtool/signtool.exe"/>
```

to

```
<property name="sign.tool" value="C:/Project/tools/signtool/signtool.exe"/>
```

Thanks.